# CompletableFuture controlled way abort on exception

Tags: java, future, java.util.concurrent, completable-future

Let's suppose I have a [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) with a couple of stages chained:

```
processedFuture = someCompletableFuture
    .thenApply(<stage1>)
    .thenApply(<stage2>)
```

And let's assume that in case an error happens in `<stage1>` we would like to abort the execution of `<stage2>` and return `SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE`. Given the following options:

```
// Option A
val mayFailFuture = someCompletableFuture
    .thenApply(<stage1>);

if (mayFailFuture.isCompletedExceptionally()) {
    log.error(...);
    return SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE;
}

processedFuture = mayFailFuture.thenApply(<stage2>)
```

```
// Option B
processedFuture = someCompletableFuture
    .thenApply(<stage1>)              // returns CompletableFuture<T>
    .exceptionally(<exceptionally1>)  // must return CompletableFuture<T>
    .thenApply(<stage2>)
```

Is *Option A* the correct way to abort a chained execution of stages? 
In *Option B* is there any way to abort the execution and return `SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE`?

Comment: Your question is based on a false premise. If stage1 throws and exception then stage2 will never be run. You don't need either of your "solutions". The original code already does what you want.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't precise enough. The point is that I need to abort the execution in a controlled way, returning some default value, I'll edit my question.

Comment: Then neither of your solutions is what you want. Option B will return a default value, then feed that into stage2. Sounds like you want `.thenApply(stage1).thenApply(stage2).exceptionally(foo)`, where foo returns the default value in the case of a failure in *either* of stage1 or stage2. For a failure in stage1, stage2 will never run.

Comment: https://ideone.com/Rx5uWT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return your default value when stage1 completes exceptionally, you could consider using `handle(BiConsumer)`:

```
processedFuture = someCompletableFuture
    .thenApply(<stage1>)
    .handle((s1Result, s1Exception) -> {
        if(s1Exception!=null) return SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE; //Exception was thrown in S1
        else return stage2.apply(s1Result); //apply stage2 otherwise
    })
```

**Edit:**

Michael already posted a better solution in comments, which is to apply `exceptionally` at the end:

```
processedFuture = someCompletableFuture
    .thenApply(<stage1>)
    .thenApply(<stage2>)
    .exceptionally(e -> SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE);
```

Just bear in mind that stage2 never executes if stage1 throws an Exception, in which case that same Exception is propagated to `exceptionally`.

**Edit 2:**

As per comment, if you wish to return different default values depending on which stage failed, this should do the trick:

```
processedFuture = someCompletableFuture
    .thenApply(<stage1>)
    .handle((s1Result, s1Exception) -> {
        if(s1Exception!=null) return DEFAULT_VALUE_1; //Exception was thrown in S1
        else return stage2.apply(s1Result); //apply stage2 otherwise
    })
    .exceptionally(e -> DEFAULT_VALUE_2); //treat exceptional return from stage2
```

Comment: And, if I want to distinguish and return `DEFAULT_VALUE_1` in case of failure on `<stage1>` and `DEFAULT_VALUE_2` in case of failure on `<stage2>'?

Comment: Then you can chain `.exceptionally(e -> DEFAULT_VALUE_2)` after the `.handle(...)` call.